# New C-like language support - Eclipse Xtext vs Eclipse CDT vs Netbeans (JavaCC, ...)

Tags: c, eclipse, netbeans, ide, programming-languages

We are trying at CERN to make support for language which is quite similar to C (Control script Language). It is not compiled but interpreted and we want to make editor for writing code easily.

We have already developed plugin for Eclipse (Xtext) which can parse source code and do some static code analysis. But lots of stuff is still missing so we were wondering if we can use C/C++ plugin in Eclipse/Netbeans and modify it. This plugins already have like 70% of what we need.

So my question is:

- Is it possible to use some existing solution (and which one) for C-like language, modify it and add our own stuff?
- What does Eclipse CDT offers for developing IDE which meets our needs
- How hard it is to take C/C++ plugin from Netbeans and change parse that way that it can be able to parse and analyze our language?

Thx for answers. ;-)

Comment: I believe these things rely on compiler output for some code analysis, which is going to limit your ability to modify it unless your interpreter can be swapped in for the same purpose.

Comment: We want to analyse just source code (Abstract Syntax Tree). It should help users see resulting type of expression which branches in code are unreachable and some other things that can potentially cause bug.

Answer (score 0):

If interpreting is all you need then you should check-out [XBase](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Xbase) base language of XText. It would be a much more realizable plan than modifying the huge C++ grammar.